# jQuery - Get the data from a cell in a selected row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this snippet of code, testing whether or not I am getting results:

```
$("#texts tr").on("click", function(evt){
    var parent_id = $(("td")[0]).text();
    alert(parent_id);
});
```

And it delivers nothing, so I imagine I have constructed my attempt at retrieving the data improperly?

UPDATE: html (generated using jade views in Node)

```
extends layout
//- Format for displaying list of texts

block content
    h1 Equity Texts
    table.table.table-striped.table-hover.table-bordered
        thead
            tr
                th Objid
                th Book Title
            tbody#texts
                each text in texts
                    tr(id = "book_" + text.objid)
                        td= text.objid
                        td= text.book_title


    script(src="/jquery.min.js",type="text/javascript")
    script(src="/handler.js",type="text/javascript")
```

Comment: You are probably getting the text of another TD in main html page not in your target area. Please bring your html too.

Comment: Can you update to show the html of the table to go with your jquery?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to get text of the first td of the clicked tr. Try this instead:

```
$("#texts tr").on("click", function(){
    var parent_id = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    alert(parent_id);
});
```

You can replace `td:first` with `td:eq(0)`

Comment: If I replace td:first wit with td[0] I get back a blank. In quotes in returns nothing. Without quotes it is an error.

Comment: Try `td:eq(0)` instead

Comment: Cool. That worked. Thanks. And now I see how to reference specific cells.

Answer (score 1):

The selector is `t` which doesn't select any elements. The code snippet `("td")[0]`  returns `t` and you are passing it as a selector to jQuery.

For getting text content of the first `td` element you can code:

```
// you probably wanted to use this syntax
$( $('td')[0] ).text();
// other alternatives
$("td").eq(0).text();
$("td:eq(0)").text();
$("td").first().text();
```

Comment: Right. I just saw that by outputting Json.stringify on the object I was accessing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just found another answer that works also. Thanks for the assist.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615825/how-to-access-specific-cell-of-clicked-table-row-in-javascript](http://%22Cells%22%20property%20on%20table%20row%20elements)

I didn't know about the cells property. If that isn't deprecated at this point.